# Extending an SSH SOCKS5 Proxy to the Far Endpoint

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I currently have this situation:

I have three machines. Call them:

1. **host-client**: Windows 7 running the OpenSSH 6.0p1 client under Cygwin
2. **host-ssh-jump-server**: Windows 7 running the OpenSSH 6.0p1 server under Cygwin
3. **host-server**: Debian 8.9 running the OpenSSH 6.7p1
   server, and running an http server on port **8080**

**host-client** opens a SOCKS5 proxy as follows:

```
ssh -D localhost:1080 -N my-username@host-ssh-jump-server
```

On **host-client**, the web browser is configured to use a SOCKS5 proxy at **localhost:1080**.

The user browses to the web server running on **host-server** from **host-client** by entering the following URL into the browser:

```
http://host-server:8080
```

The problem is that the connection between **host-client** and **host-server** is unencrypted on the hop between **host-ssh-jump-server** and **host-server**.

At this moment, getting HTTPS running on **host-server** is not an option. I need a stopgap. I need to extend the SSH tunnel all the way to **host-server**.

To minimize user disruption, I would like to do this with these constraints:

- Don't change the SOCKS5 proxy they create on **host-client**.
- Don't change the URL they use to browse to **host-server**, except possibly for the port number.
- Other (unrelated) applications traverse the SOCKS5 proxy. They must not be disrupted.
- Any new tunnels that would be created would need to have the listening port be bound to **localhost** for security.

How may I do this, or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ssh -L localhost:1080:localhost:1080 my-username@host-ssh-jump-server -t 'ssh -N -D localhost:1080 root@host-server'
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with your detail, consider adding some reference and proof supporting what you state.