# Double SOCKS5 proxy using SSH

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, proxy

I was searching for a way to connect to one of my servers who is behind a jumpbox via SSH. I was able to do so by running the following command:

```
$ ssh -tt ptitpou@jumpbox ssh -tt ptitpou@targetserver
```

Now, I want to be able to use that server to access webservers on `targetserver`'s network. For that, I followed [this quora answer](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-set-up-a-two-hop-SOCKS5-proxy-over-ssh) and I was able to successfully access the websites. The command I used was:

```
$ ssh -L 127.0.0.1:9999:localhost:9696 -tt ptitpou@jumpbox ssh -D 9696 -tt ptitpou@targetserver
```

The question I want to ask is how to use the `ssh -o ProxyCommand` to command in a slightly cleaner way. I tried to put the second part of the command as the proxy command and I had a successful SSH connection, but I was unable to use the proxy after that.

I've also tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1248609/extending-an-ssh-socks5-proxy-to-the-far-endpoint) but the command line hangs after connecting to `targetserver`.

How can I do that? Am I wrong to try to use `ProxyCommand` option for this task?

Comment: Can you add the SSH version on each server and client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using openssh. The easiest way to do it is to use ProxyJump which appeared recently. You can use it from command line, effectively having the following command:

```
ssh -J ptitpou@jumpbox -D 9999 -tt ptitpou@targetserver
```

or from config file:

```
Host targetserver
    ProxyJump ptitpou@jumpbox
    DynamicForward 9999
```

Alternatively you can use ProxyCommand:

```
Host targetserver
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p ptitpou@jumpbox
    DynamicForward 9999
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I needed to edit it a little, otherwise I was getting error : `bind [::1]:9999: Cannot assign requested address`. This was the line that worked for me : `ssh -J ptitpou@jumpbox -D 127.0.0.1:9999 -tt ptitpou@targetserver`

Comment: Apparently your ssh insists on using IPv6 and your system doesn't support / enable it...